# Is there an algorithm for memory-efficient rank change tracking?

Tags: algorithm, relational-database, ranking

For a racing game, I have this highscore table (it contains more columns to indicate the race track and other things, but let's ignore that):

```
Rank | ID    | Time  | Datetime    | Player
   1 | 4ef9b | 8.470 | today 13:00 | Bob
   2 | 23fcf | 8.470 | today 13:04 | Carol
   3 | d8512 | 8.482 | today 12:47 | Alice
null | 0767c | 9.607 | today 12:51 | Alice
null | eec81 | 9.900 | today 12:55 | Bob
```

The Rank column is precomputed and reflects `ORDER BY Time, Datetime` but uniqued such that each player has only their best entry ranked. (The non-personal-best records, with `null` Rank, are relevant for historic graphs.)

When inserting a new highscore, there are at least two ways to update the ranks:

- Insert the new row and invalidate their old rank, then periodically read the whole table using `ORDER BY`, deduplicate players, and issue UPDATE queries in batches of 1000 by using long lists of `CASE id WHEN 4ef9b THEN rank=1, WHEN 23fcf THEN rank=2, etc., END`. The database server is clever enough that if I try setting Carol's rank to 2 again, it will see it's the same and not do a disk write, so it's less-than-horribly inefficient.
- Only update the rows that were changed by doing:

  1. oldID, oldRank = `SELECT ID, Rank WHERE Player=$player, Rank IS NOT NULL`
  2. newRank = `SELECT MAX(Rank) WHERE time < $newTime`;
  3. `UPDATE Rank+=1 WHERE Rank IS NOT NULL AND Rank >= $newRank AND Rank < $oldRank`
  4. `INSERT (Rank=$newRank, Time=$newTime, Player=..., etc.)`
  5. `UPDATE Rank=null WHERE ID=$oldID`

I implemented the latter because it seemed to be optimally efficient (only selecting and touching rows that need changing), but this actually took the server down upon a flood of new personal best times due to new level releases. It turns out that *periodically* doing the less-efficient former method actually creates a lot less load, but I'd have to implement a queueing mechanism for rank invalidation which feels like extra complexity on top of inefficiency.

One problem I have is that my database calls `fsync` after each query (and has severe warnings against turning that off), so doing 100 row updates in one query might take 0.83 seconds whereas doing 100 queries takes `100 × (fsync_time+query_time)` = e.g. 1000×0.51 = 51 seconds. This might be why changing Rank rows along with every insert is such a burden on the system, so I want to batch this by storing an ordered list of `(oldrank, newrank)` pairs and applying them all at once.

**What algorithm can be used to compute the batch update?** I could select the whole ranked list from the database into a big hashmap (`map[rank] = ID`), apply any number of rank changes to this memory object, build big `CASE WHEN` strings to update a thousand rows in one query, and send those updates to the database. However, as the number of players grows, this hashmap might not fit in memory.

Is there a way to do this based on **ranges of ranks, instead of individual ranks?** The list of incoming changes, such as:

- Bob moves from rank 500 to rank 1
- Carol moves from rank 350 to rank 100

should turn into a list of changes to make for each rank:

- rank[1-99] +=1
- rank[100-349] += 2
- rank[351-499] += 1

without having a memory object that needs `O(n)` memory, where `n` is the number of ranked scores in the database for one race track. In this case, the two changes expand to three ranges, spanning five hundred rank entries. (Changing each row in the database will still have to happen; this can probably not be helped without entirely changing the setup.)

I am using a standard LAMP stack, in case that is relevant for an answer.

Comment: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/sorted-sets/ is intended for this use case.  Is it essential that you use a database for this?  Also you should understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control well if you want to avoid race conditions.

Comment: @btilly Thank you for the pointers, I'll check those out